# How to disable "yum install <local file>"?

Tags: installation, local, yum, rhel7, disable

On some RHEL7/CentOS7 servers, application admins without full root rights should be able to do `sudo yum install *` to install any RPM from enabled repositories.
Since `yum install` can also be used to install RPMs from any other URL, e.g. local files, there should be a way to prevent exactly that.

I checked the yum documentation but found only `exclude` and `includepkgs` options. Although I could just exclude everything, maintaining `includepkgs` is almost impossible since the enabled repositories might change at any time.

Is there any other way to force yum to install only packages from enabled repositories and disallow packages from any other source?